# Re-install src/lib/python folder in a Django project

Tags: python, django

I have a Django project and I messed up with the src/lib/python folder (I know I shouldn't have but that's the case) and now I have missing files and folders.

How can I re-install the python folder in order to retrieve the missing files?

Comment: How did you create that directory in the first place? Is it part of a virtualenv?

Comment: @DanielRoseman yes it is part of a virtualenv. Do I now have to re-install it?

Comment: Yes, just recreating the virtualenv should fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, according to @DanielRoseman recreating the virtualenv should fix the problem.